# Combinaciones "explosivas" Avatar-Sombrero del SumTer Bash

Tags: discusión

Recorriendo algunos usuarios noté estas combinaciones interesantes entre Avatar y Sombreros del **SumTer Bash**:

**Un StormTrooper con gorro de invierno!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Darth Vader metalero (guitarrista)!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Darth Vader pop (bajista)!** (nos falta el baterista y se armó la **"Band Vader"**)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por último el Yeti en la playa.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Alguien encontró otras?**

Comment: acabas de encontrar al batería... cuando queráis

Comment: Se armó **Band Vader** entonces...

Comment: Yo Soy mas del **pop vader**

Comment: @MiquelColl Editado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este avatar **ES LA COMBINACIÓN EXPLOSIVA del SumTer Bash** ya que reune 3 clásicos en uno:

1. ET
2. Jurassic Park
3. Star wars..

Sería un **Darth-Nosaurio ET-X** (Si se les ocurre uno mejor...se acepta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7):

Os presento a **Sir** Alvaro montoro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Remember Remember the 5th of November *at night*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @aldanux estaría en "anonymous menguante?"

Comment: @PabloClaus - jajaja  - Pero muy bien redactado @@MiquelColl [Remember the 5th of November at night](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Fawkes#Legado) :D

Comment: @PabloClaus de hecho la luna esta en creciente xD

Comment: @lois6b jeje. Aunque este no es un sitio de astronomia...la realidad es que depende del emisferio donde estes en el norte puede ser creciente y en el sur menguante.

Comment: @PabloClaus :O cierto. siempre pensando en mi zona .. sorry

Comment: @lois6b lol. Suele pasar. Ahora hay que acostumbrarse al multi-hemisferio. Saludos!

Answer (score 7):

Aquí está Konamiman con orejas de conejo... Kawaii.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5):

¿Tal vez...**un sonriente hombre de las nieves**? :D

[image: Hat #1]

---

**Alguien está un poco enojado y triste**<sup>1</sup>

[image: Hat #2]

<sup>1</sup>*El título puede cambiar :)*

Comment: Pensé que estaba bostezando ja

Answer (score 5):

Por ahora zorro menguante.

[image: Zorro menguante.]

Comment: Hahaha muy buena! Máscara encima de máscara!

Comment: @MiquelColl es una máscara "anidada".

Comment: acabo de fijarme. .. no es "zorro creciente" ?X D

Comment: ¡Sí! Espero este año haya novedades

Answer (score 4):

¿Alguien ha llamado al sombrero loco?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Este era el StormTrooper que investigaba para el imperio...(Sherlock Trooper)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elemental mi querido @Pablo

Comment: @Mariano no pensé que una máscara sería tan universal

Answer (score 3):

Y así como vinieron,
se fueron sin dejar nada,
nada más que una captura...

[image: Mariano]

Fue divertido mientras duró.

¡Hasta WB 2017!

Comment: Esa si que fue una coleccion!!! Te felicito.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo. Me entretuvo bastante. Ya se siente raro estar sin sombrero

Comment: O con uno solo ;)

Comment: ¡Buena colección! Vaya ropero que se arma ese Storm Trooper.

Comment: La verdad @JuanM es que empecé sin darle importancia, pero cuando vi que había obtenido muchos, que algunos eran difíciles, y que estaba bien posicionado en la general, fui por más... Tuve varias situaciones divertidas en estas 3 semanas