# Desfile Winter Bash 2017

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2017

¡¡¡[Winter Bash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) de nuevo!!!   <sub><sup>(Anuncio en el blog: [Winter Bash 2017: Greatest <strike>Hits</strike> Hats!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats-2/))</sup></sub>

Me tomó por sorpresa ver el [image: copo de nieve] ahí arriba otra vez. Al principio me agarré la cabeza sabiendo lo que se venía (esta vez me va a costar mucho más ganarlos)... pero sólo por un instante. En seguida ya estaba divirtiéndome con mi primer "sombrero".

[image: Mi primer sombrero no es un sombrero(?)]

<sup>- Pueden encontrar más detalles de cada sombrero (incluyendo los secretos) en *[Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/304899)*</sup>

Al igual que [el año pasado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1194/127), ¿cuáles son los sombreros que mejor se llevan? ¿Qué usuario les llamó la atención? ¿cuál está a la moda?

Publiquemos algunas imágenes.

Comment: Me cogieron de sorpresa hace unos minutos, yo no sabía que eran, estaba a punto de hacer una pregunta acá jejeje son geniales !!! ya tengo 2 :D

Comment: Mariano tu sombrero  en realidad es un scarf! 

Comment: Yo me he cambiado la foto de perfil para que los sombreros puedan ser usados con ***cabeza*** XDD cuando acabe el winter bash vuelvo a LotusSuicide

Comment: Como dice @lois6b hace falta cabeza para usar sombrero, así que he robado una en un huerto cercano y me he traido un sombrero de SO ya que aquí no he conseguido ninguno todavía.

Comment: La lista de sombreros secretos descubiertos hasta ahora se puede ver en https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats/304341

Comment: Terminó winter-bash 2017 nos vemos el próximo año https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/es.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 17):

Como en todo caso, SO tambien nos trae la solución a la alopecia...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias Lamak por tanto...

Comment: ese sombrero me vendría muy bien a mi XDD

Comment: @Joacer a mi también! haha!, además sería de mucha ayuda para este frio! :)

Answer (score 9):

De momento mi preferida es el León Sombrerero Loco de Xerif:

[image: Xerif]

Comment: Wow! un león con sombrero! :D

Comment: jajaja, si quedo bien...

Answer (score 9):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola Jorgelina!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Perdio su recursividad mas no su elegancia, les presento a.......
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualizo..**

*Elegancia y Recursividad en (n x m) mostacho*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahhh haha sería cool fuera recursivo!

Comment: Para Marc --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2DMx.png

Comment: Jajajaja @Mariano

Comment: @Mariano Actualizado!

Comment: ya le hice un upgrade a la version!

Answer (score 7):

¿Está mal que ponga mi propia foto de perfil?

No esperaba conseguir [este sombrero](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/silencium) y la verdad, queda muy bien con el sofá y la pipa.

Muy *like a sir*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece hecho a medida Sir Lois

Answer (score 6):

Me ha sorprendido encontrar a este "personaje" con un sombrero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un poco absurdo que el usuario Comunidad, teniendo semejante server a disposición, prefiera [votar con la aplicación mobile](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/too-cool).

Answer (score 5):

Soy un perro con sombrero que parece perro, QUE EMPIECE LA PARADOJA TEMPORAL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Yo me quedo con la gorra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Un gorro convertido en orejas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ezequiel, parece un gatito, un gato hombre! =0

Comment: @Jorgesys Jeje, recuerdo esa entrevista, estaba un poco nervioso, pero creo que estuve bien.