# ¡Veamos cómo os quedan los sombreros!

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2019, winterbash

Como ya es tradición en estas épocas, los sombreros adornan a los usuarios. Como en ediciones anteriores, ¡veamos qué tal quedan!

- [Edición 2016](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194/combinaciones-explosivas-avatar-sombrero-del-sumter-bash)
- [Edición 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/desfile-winter-bash-2017)
- [Edición 2018](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3774/tienes-cabeza-para-usar-sombrero-lleg%C3%B3-el-winter-bash-2018/3780#3780)

Comment: @fedorqui si editastes debes agregar una imagen aqui con un sombrero no seas pillo todos te vemos

Comment: @Jack jeje no llevo este año, no me apetece usar los jueguecitos de SE después del año que nos han dado a todos

Comment: Ojalá saliesen con más frecuencia hilos offtopic como este en meta para pasar un buen rato :-)

Answer (score 13):

Lo primero que conseguí, en vez de sombrero, fue una nueva maleta:

[image: Maleta]

Después un extraño vehículo propulsado por hélice, en el que podía viajar sentado (aunque un poco encogido)

[image: ovni]

Luego no sé qué pasó que transmuté en calamar. Será cosa del tipado dinámico.

[image: Calamar]

Ahora por fin tengo un sombrero acorde a mi posición en el Ministry of Silly Walks.

[image: silly]

Al que añado los complementos de malabarista

[image: malabarista]

Comment: Genial el avatar y la mejor versión la que sale escapando en el gorrocóptero al más puro estilo Doctor Robotnik.

Comment: para mi parece abulafia montado en la nave de bowser

Comment: tu gorro maleta ya no existe

Comment: @lois6b que pides que actualice la respuesta?

Comment: naah, no hace falta claro

Answer (score 9):

Hay veces que pienso extraño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

otras veces ando por las nubes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o navegando en los mares

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando logro algo me siento como un heroe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque hay veces que me noto sometido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Molan mucho todos, pero el primero es el que más me gusta porque, además de conseguir satélites para tu pelota, llevas turbante enjoyado :-)

Comment: @abulafia pues ni me habia fijado jajajaj

Answer (score 8):

Siempre elegante para las misiones (de aprender a programar....)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A veces me invade el ánimo de carnaval y programo al ritmo del código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Preparen IDE, programen...... Compilennnnn

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Últimamente está es mi expresión cuando veo cuánto he aprendido JS y lo más que me va gustando cada día

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el último (al momento) que no se como explicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mejor el último, me recuerda a un katamari flipando con un tripi.

Answer (score 8):

GatoCornio, un extraño ser mitológico malvado que solo se le ve por estas fechas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 8):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Gandalf de Hacendado, subiendo el commit único al Monte del Hardcodeo

Answer (score 8):

¡Buen día!

Éste fue mi primer sombrero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego vino éste: Y se convirtió en mi favorito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego vino este que no sé porqué me lo dieron:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y claro, que no falte el carnavalero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, ¡Feliz codificación!

Comment: Me gusta el primero, bigote + mohawk

Answer (score 6):

Fanático de SO:

Extraña condición médica en la que a la persona le nace un unicornio cíclope en la panza, capaz de ver las preguntas que deben marcarse para cierre.

[image: sombrero de badge dorado]

Usualmente causado por entrar 100 días consecutivos a SO.

Comment: no paras de presumir tu medalla ehhm?

Comment: Jamááaaaaaassssssss