# Día de inocentes, ¿Existe alguna sección para hacer preguntas falsas, respuestas, etc en estos días?

Tags: discusión

StackOverflow tiene dos eventos el de navidad y April's fool como tal para gran parte de la comunidad hispano hablante día de inocentes se celebra el 28 de diciembre, pero como tal no existe un evento para esas fechas puesto que esta activo el de navidad quiero suponer, pero me gustaría que se incluyera dicho día, pero lo más importante seria interesante ver una sección en la cual se pudiera hacer preguntas de broma y también sus respuestas comentarios, tambien se me ocurre dar puntos exagerados por pregunta o respuestas, claro también de broma,claro que sea una sección, de este modo no perjudicar el funcionamiento y objetivo de la pagina, también que cuente con reglas ya saben no insultos y pues la moderación de las preguntas o respuestas, pienso seria entretenido tener dicha sección de día de inocentes ya sea en abril o el 28 de diciembre para ser más amenos con la comunidad en español.

Comment: Excelente propuesta, secundo la moción.

Comment: Casi no te entendí por la mala redacción, aunque... me parece una buena idea, estaría entretenido leer las respuestas de algunos usuarios muy creativos.

Comment: @miguel-clavijo No estuve el día 28, ¿sabemos si hubo algún post de broma? ¿Podríamos enlazarlo?

Comment: @ordago yo conozco al menos dos post de broma [en 2018](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225984/2742) y [en 2019](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/318713/2742).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Buenas bromas xD. Espero que este año 2020 nos cueles alguna para el 1 de abril o el 28 de diciembre.

Comment: @ordago 28 de diciembre será. Pero cuesta encontrar ideas (por suerte, tengo casi un año para pensarlo).

Comment: También lo hace difícil que la pregunta sea de broma pero que cumpla con las normas de la comunidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo hice hace un par de años [Cambiar el tipo de letra a comic sans en el editor de Visual Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/127561/2027). Creo que solo lo anuncié en el chat, tal vez recopilarlas en el chat o abrir una sección en meta con los del año, como los [sombreros](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4479/2027).

Sería importante recalcar que fueran preguntas que sí deben permanecer el en sitio.

Comment: Pero como tal alcanza ser una pregunta que sigue los estándares de la pagina, seria cherchare poder hacer preguntas como, ¿Que pasa si se me olvida respirar?, cosas de ese estilo.

Comment: @MiguelClavijo preguntas asi, mas alla del humor, no entrarian dentro de los parametros del sitio. Hay otros sitios que mas alla de esta fecha usan un periodo para hacer preguntas con humor, pero dentro de los parametros del sitio. En realidad de hacer algo asi, deberian ser preguntas como la señalada aca

Comment: <netflix:paulina de la vega>Es-ta-- i-dea-es - ra-ri-ta</netflix:paulina de la vega>

Comment: @MiguelClavijo también es pensado en no dar mas trabajo a los mosd y las colas de revisión